# pgAdmin popup window with message: edit table data without primary key

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pgAdmin, When I am open view table data, popup window are opened with title: `edit table data without primary key`, please see screenshot.

I  add primary key column on table:

```
alter table users add column id bigserial primary key
```

though, this popup window still opened, when trying view table data.

Cann you tell me please what is wrong here?

postgresql version is `9.3`

pgAdmin version is `1.18.1`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgAdmin takes a look at the database when you open it and then you are working with that snapshot. Any changes made will only be visible to pgAdmin after you do a "refresh". This is a right-click menu option on most objects in the object tree.

So even while you know you have changed the table and the changes are in the database (you can use the SQL editor to verify that), pgAdmin doesn't - an object tree refresh (in your case on your table `users`) fixes that.